# What are the default Lifetime values for openiddict tokens

Tags: c#, .net, openid-connect, openid, openiddict

Very simple question, i would just like to know what the default values are set in openiddict 3.0+

Tokens are

- AccessToken
- AuthorizationToken
- DeviceCodeToken
- IdentityToken
- RefreshToken
- UserCodeToken

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

You find the default lifetimes of the different tokens in the source code here:

https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/dev/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerOptions.cs

The most important lifetimes are:

```
public TimeSpan? AuthorizationCodeLifetime { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
public TimeSpan? AccessTokenLifetime { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
public TimeSpan? IdentityTokenLifetime { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
public TimeSpan? RefreshTokenLifetime { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
public TimeSpan? UserCodeLifetime { get; set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question

Comment: While this answer pointed me in the right direction and has my upvote. It would be even better if it states the actual values in case the link goes dead.

Comment: I added the default values to my answer

Comment: Thanks. I could change the default Access token lieftime to 1 minute for testing.

Comment: When playing around with the token lifetime, do watch out for the ClowSkew parameter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.clockskew?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest#microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-tokenvalidationparameters-clockskew