# Replace IdentityServer with Openiddict in .NET 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, openiddict

I'm migrating my project from using IdentityServer v6 to Openiddict and having a hard time finding Openiddict stuff similar to IdentityServer.

Currently in Identity server, we have **Client** to represent OpenID Connect or OAuth2 client:

```
 new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client_example",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    ClientSecrets = clientSecret,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "scope_1", "scope_2", },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
                    AccessTokenLifetime = accessTokenLifetime,
                    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 0,
                    c= TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = refreshTokenLifetime
                }
```

According to Openiddict document, I created a Seeder to seed my Clients:

```
await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
            {
                ClientId = "client_example",
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                ConsentType = ConsentTypes.Explicit,
                DisplayName = "Client Example Test",
                RedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:7002/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html")
                },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://localhost:7002/resources")
                },
                Permissions =
                {
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Logout,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                    Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                   $"{Permissions.Prefixes.Scope}scope1",
                   $"{Permissions.Prefixes.Scope}scope2"
                },    
            })
```

How can i change the **AccessTokenLifetime** ,**AccessTokenLifetime** and others related stuffs for each client like what i have with Identity Server.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own authentication server? That's what OpenIDDict is about. It's not a ready-made server. Perhaps you should look for a ready-made server instead?

Comment: Yes i'm trying to create my own authentication server sir. Because I have numerous of Client type and scope for each service. And each services now has its own token behaviors so I'm a little bit of confuse here when trying to replace Identity Server with Openiddict

Answer (score 2):

As the answer to [What are the default Lifetime values for openiddict tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297169/what-are-the-default-lifetime-values-for-openiddict-tokens) shows, token settings are stored in `OpenIddictServerOptions`. You can modify the default settings using  the [OpenIddictServerBuilder.Configure(Action)](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/3dc3e010097c96fb6e47f7bacd1cb33afe1ddba0/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerBuilder.cs#L117) method or the various [Set...LifeTime](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/3dc3e010097c96fb6e47f7bacd1cb33afe1ddba0/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerBuilder.cs#L1665) methods inside [AddServer](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/3dc3e010097c96fb6e47f7bacd1cb33afe1ddba0/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerExtensions.cs#L100C86-L100C109).

For example :

```
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        //Set Lifetime options
        options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
               .SetAuthorizationCodeLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

        // Enable the token endpoint.
        options.SetTokenEndpointUris("connect/token");
        ...
    })
```

The `Set` methods can be chained because they return the `options` object.

The same pattern is used for other objects too. If you search the source repository for `LifeTime` you'll find [OpenIddictClientBuilder.SetStateTokenLifetime](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/3dc3e010097c96fb6e47f7bacd1cb33afe1ddba0/src/OpenIddict.Client/OpenIddictClientBuilder.cs#L1152), fine-grained methods like [public static ClaimsPrincipal SetAccessTokenLifetime(this ClaimsPrincipal principal, TimeSpan? lifetime)](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/3dc3e010097c96fb6e47f7bacd1cb33afe1ddba0/src/OpenIddict.Abstractions/Primitives/OpenIddictExtensions.cs#L3040) and more

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If i has for example like 10 resourse API server, can i modify default settings for each of them sir?